# What Windows SVN+Tasks Management+Blog+Timeline free, Open Source solutions are there?

Tags: windows, svn, blogs

What Windows SVN+Task Management+Blog+Timeline free, Open Source solutions (projects) are there?

Comment: Are you looking for an all in one solution? Not sure there is one package, but you can a lot of OS integrate task management / bug tracking projects into SVN repositories. You may want to look at VersionOne community edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/):

**Windows SVN**
Yes, it's a web based application that can run on a Windows or Linux server, and can be accessed by either Windows or Linux clients

**Tasks**
Yes, they're referred to as "tickets"

**Management**
Yes, there is a "Roadmap" feature that does project management based on milestones, ticket durations, and creates a schedule.

**Blog**
Yes, Trac has a wiki that users can create and edit

**Timeline**
Yes, Trac has it. Allows you to browse source, see svn log, etc.

**free, opensource**
Trac is free and open source

Answer (score 2):

Redmine is a very good open source system that supports most if not all of your listed operations.  www.redmine.org

It is available in ready-to-use bitnami stacks for Windows, Linux, Solaris, etc.  www.bitnami.org

Answer (score 0):

FogBugz can integrate with the most popular source control systems and supports issue tracking and planning (presumably what you mean by *timeline*). While it doesn't support blogs, it supports wikis, which should be sufficient if you want to use it for documentation.

While not open source, it has a free [student/startup version](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/StudentAndStartup.html) if you only need two accounts.